# GitHub Branch name from which the Pull Request is raised

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request, multibranch-pipeline

I'm using Multibranch Pipeline Job in Jenkins.

How do I find the branch name from which the Pull Request is raised in GitHub?

I'm using `/github-webhook/` & also tried with `/ghprbhook/` and tried with the following environment variables: `GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH`, `GIT_BRANCH`, `ghprbSourceBranch`, but I didn't get any result.

If there are any suggestions, I would love to try them.

Answer (score 36):

`CHANGE_BRANCH` gives the correct name of the source branch of the PR.

`CHANGE_TARGET` gives the target name of the PR merge

Comment: Interesting, while this is not mentioned in the [multibranch pipeline documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#additional-environment-variables), the code in [branch-api](https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/c4d394415cf25b6890855a08360119313f1330d2/src/main/resources/jenkins/branch/BranchNameContributor/buildEnv.jelly) plugin mentions those.

Comment: What about non-PR builds? I'd like to have a single Jenkinsfile for my builds. Do I then have to detect if CHANGE_BRANCH exists, and then assume it isn't a PR build?

Comment: @trusktr Yes, if CHANGE_BRANCH exists, it means it's a PR build. Otherwise CHANGE_BRANCH doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

The environment variable `CHANGE_BRANCH` should give you the source branch name and `CHANGE_TARGET` the target branch name. For PR from forks, the `CHANGE_FORK` gives you the repository name of the fork. For PR from origin, `CHANGE_FORK` is not set.

To see the description of the environment variables, navigate to a branch job then **Pipeline Syntax > Global Variable Reference > env**. It should display [the description of those variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/branch-api-2.6.3/src/main/resources/jenkins/branch/BranchNameContributor/buildEnv.properties).

Comment: Nice one mentioning about the Jenkins link describing all available env variables.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different parameters and it can be difficult to find the correct one depending on the context.

> **BRANCH_NAME**
>
> For a multibranch project, this will be set to the name of the branch being built, for example in case you wish to deploy to production from `master` but not from feature branches; if corresponding to some kind of change request, the name is generally arbitrary (refer to `CHANGE_ID` and `CHANGE_TARGET`).

This can either be the branch name (like in branch builds) or some other identifier (like the pull request Id). The documentation is clear that it can be either, but it is surprising behavior if you haven't read the full documentation.

The [other answer by MZ2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47788979/627727) shows a way that will *probably* work as the checkout. It may depend on plugin versions and is probably affected by the same issue as above.

```
def scmVars = checkout scm
def branchName = scmVars.GIT_BRANCH
```

The way that that you can get it is if you use the [*GitHub Branch Source Plugin*](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin) which supports the `CHANGE_BRANCH` environment variable. This was added in [JENKINS-43418](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43418) and you should be able to reference it if you are using `env.CHANGE_BRANCH`. It may not be available in Multibranch jobs, though.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#additional-environment-variables), the pull request ID is exposed as `CHANGE_ID` variable.

Btw. environment variables can be accessed in pipeline's groovy code via `env`, such as `env.CHANGE_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

For multibranch pipelines, use:

```
env.BRANCH_NAME
```

for accessing the branch name.

Edit: If you need to debug env variables or git variables you can try:

1. access GIT variables

   ```
   def scmVars = checkout scm
   def branchName = scmVars.GIT_BRANCH
   ```
2. Print ENV variables

   ```
   sh("printenv")
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I raise a PR and use this command, we are getting PR number as the branch name.

Comment: that is strange. Maybe you can try printing all env vars and git vars to see if the branch name is stored in another variable?

Comment: This doesn't work. Jenkins make a branch like `PR-XXX` where `XXX` is the PR number, and that is what shows up in `env.BRANCH_NAME`. Wish it put the PR's original branch name in there!